# Python - How to generate the Pairwise Hamming Distance Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, hamming-distance

beginner with Python here. So I'm having trouble trying to calculate the resulting binary pairwise hammington distance matrix between the rows of an input matrix  using only the numpy library. I'm supposed to avoid loops and use vectorization. If for instance I have something like:

```
   [ 1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0]
   [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
   [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0]
```

The matrix should be something like:

```
   [ 0,  2,  3]
   [ 2,  0,  3]
   [ 3,  3,  0]
```

ie if the original matrix was A and the hammingdistance matrix is B. B[0,1] = hammingdistance (A[0] and A[1]). In this case the answer is 2 as they only have two different elements.

So for my code is something like this

```
def compute_HammingDistance(X):

     hammingDistanceMatrix = np.zeros(shape = (len(X), len(X)))
     hammingDistanceMatrix = np.count_nonzero ((X[:,:,None] != X[:,:,None].T))
     return hammingDistanceMatrix
```

However it seems to just be returning a scalar value instead of the intended matrix. I know I'm probably doing something wrong with the array/vector broadcasting but I can't figure out how to fix it. I've tried using np.sum instead of np.count_nonzero but they all pretty much gave me something similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this approach, create a new axis along `axis = 1`, and then do broadcasting and count trues or non zero with `sum`:

```
(arr[:, None, :] != arr).sum(2)

# array([[0, 2, 3],
#        [2, 0, 3],
#        [3, 3, 0]])
```

---

```
def compute_HammingDistance(X):
    return (X[:, None, :] != X).sum(2)
```

*Explanation*:

1) Create a 3d array which has shape (3,1,6)

```
arr[:, None, :]
#array([[[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]],
#       [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
#       [[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]])
```

2) this is a 2d array has shape (3, 6)

```
arr   
#array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
#       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

3) This triggers broadcasting since their shape doesn't match, and the 2d array *arr* is firstly broadcasted along the 0 axis of 3d array *arr[:, None, :]*, and then we have array of shape (1, 6) be broadcasted against (3, 6). The two broadcasting steps together make a cartesian comparison of the original array.

```
arr[:, None, :] != arr 
#array([[[False, False, False, False, False, False],
#        [False, False, False,  True,  True, False],
#        [False,  True,  True, False,  True, False]],
#       [[False, False, False,  True,  True, False],
#        [False, False, False, False, False, False],
#        [False,  True,  True,  True, False, False]],
#       [[False,  True,  True, False,  True, False],
#        [False,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
#        [False, False, False, False, False, False]]], dtype=bool)
```

4) the `sum` along the third axis count how many elements are not equal, i.e, trues which gives the hamming distance.

Comment: I replaced the original i had in my code with     hammingDistanceMatrix = np.count_nonzero((X[:, None, :] != X).sum(2)) and it still seems to give me the same result, a single scalar value.

Comment: you don't need the np.count_nonzero here. the `sum` does it for you. Just return `hammingDistanceMatrix = (arr[:, None, :] != arr).sum(2)` should be fine.

Comment: Oh, that worked! Thanks a lot. Would it be possible if you could explain why the broad cast is done arr[:,None,:] like that, and why .sum(2)?

Answer (score 5):

For reasons I do not understand this

```
(2 * np.inner(a-0.5, 0.5-a) + a.shape[1] / 2)
```

appears to be much faster than @Psidom's for larger arrays:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,2,(100,1000))
timeit(lambda: (a[:, None, :] != a).sum(2), number=100)
# 2.297890231013298
timeit(lambda: (2 * np.inner(a-0.5, 0.5-a) + a.shape[1] / 2), number=100)
# 0.10616962902713567
```

Psidom's is a bit faster for the very small example:

```
a
# array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
#        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])

timeit(lambda: (a[:, None, :] != a).sum(2), number=100)
# 0.0004370050155557692
timeit(lambda: (2 * np.inner(a-0.5, 0.5-a) + a.shape[1] / 2), number=100)
# 0.00068191799800843
```

**Update**

Part of the reason appears to be floats being faster than other dtypes:

```
timeit(lambda: (0.5 * np.inner(2*a-1, 1-2*a) + a.shape[1] / 2), number=100)
# 0.7315902590053156
timeit(lambda: (0.5 * np.inner(2.0*a-1, 1-2.0*a) + a.shape[1] / 2), number=100)
# 0.12021801102673635
```

Comment: That's a clever way of comparing elements and counting them in one go. I think the main reason floating point dtypes are faster in this case is that BLAS routines are only available for those dtypes. All other dtypes are handled by less optimized numpy C code.

Comment: @user7138814 Wow, I wasn't aware BLAS made _that_ much of a difference!